# jhipster application deployment to Heroku giving error

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jhipster, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my jhipster generated application to heroku  using ubuntu. When I type:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

, I am getting `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

But while deploying the application to heroku using jhipster command, I am getting the below error.

```
    sudo jhipster heroku


Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:heroku
Options: 
Heroku configuration is starting
Deploying as existing app: infinite-savannah-43112

Using existing Git repository

Heroku CLI deployment plugin already installed

Provisioning addons
No new addons created

Creating Heroku deployment files
identical src/main/resources/config/bootstrap-heroku.yml
identical src/main/resources/config/application-heroku.yml
identical Procfile
identical pom.xml
identical pom.xml

Building application
✖ { Error: Command failed: ./mvnw verify -DskipTests=true -B -Pprod
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:272:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:363:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:562:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: './mvnw verify -DskipTests=true -B -Pprod' }
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

Even my JAVA_HOME is pointing to  Java-8-oracle, why jhipster throwing error saying JAVA_HOME is pointing to something else and  any fix for this

Comment: Are you able to run `./mvnw verify` outside of the jhipster command? Also, you can try the Git deployment, which will build on Heroku instead of locally.

Comment: how can I change to  that Git deployment option. Because now when I run jhipster heroku, by default it is taking local build option by default. It is not asking me to select the option for Git deployment, , only first time it asked me that option. Now always by default it is going for local build option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually edit the `herokuDeployType` value in your `.yo-rc.json` to this:

```
"herokuDeployType": "git"
```

Then the next time you run `jhipster heroku` it will run Maven on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You're using JDK 9 which is not supported JHipster. You should not need to use sudo, it's very unsafe. I suppose you installed Node as sudo, you should consider reinstalling Node correctly (maybe using nvm)  and change ownership of your project's files. Your error could come from the sudo command.